# Array of objects in Javascript - using "push"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am very new with Javascript and I can't seem to find an explanation for what is happening with my code.

I want to create an array of "people" where each person has some information associated with them, like "id" and "name".  I don't know how many "people" I would need in my array so I am using "push" when I need another person.  My problem is my array ends up filled with the last person's information.

Here is my declarations that I am using:

```
var ppl_arr = [];
var profile = {
  id: 10000,
  name: " ",

};

profile.id=3;

ppl_arr.push(profile); //add this person to my array
alert(ppl_arr[0].id + "\t" + ppl_arr.length); 

profile.id=5;
ppl_arr.push(profile);  // push next person to the array
alert(ppl_arr[0].id+"\t"+ppl_arr[1].id + "\t"+ppl_arr.length);
```

The first alert displays correctly :  "3    1"
In the second alert, I get " 5    5   2"  instead of " 3    5    2"

So I get two entries into my array but the second one seems to overwrite the first one.  Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: Assigning a new value to a property of an object does not cause it to become a new object. You're simply putting the exact same object in the array twice.

Comment: Also, your first `alert()` shows `4`, not `3` (the "id" value), because you're adding two numbers together (`3` and the length of the array, which is `1`, giving `4`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply changing the id of the same object, and adding the same object to the array twice. I would suggest that you create your 'people' objects as instance objects, something like this

```
//This is a constructor function for a Person object

function Person(id,name)
{
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
}
```

then

```
var ppl_arr = [];

ppl_arr.push(new Person(3,"Bob")); //add this person to my array

alert(ppl_arr[0].Id + " - " +  ppl_arr.length); //outputs "3 - 1"
//NOTE put a string inbetween, because Id and length are both integers, 
//you would actual get a sum of the two, not a string concatenation.

ppl_arr.push(new Person(5,"Steve"));  // push next person to the array

alert(ppl_arr[0].Id+"\t"+ppl_arr[1].Id + "\t"+ppl_arr.length); // outputs 3  5  2
```

Comment: Thanks! I"m getting closer! This example helped me understand what is going on with arrays of objects.

Answer (score 2):

Question #1:

`alert(ppl_arr[0].id + ppl_arr.length);` will display the sum, not the concatenation - try `alert(ppl_arr[0].id.toString().concat(ppl_arr.length));`

Question #2:

You change the `id` property of an existing object, not copy it. So you change the id of the object already in the array as well. So you would need to

```
var ppl_arr = [];
var profile = {
  id: 10000,
  name: " ",

};

profile.id=3;
ppl_arr.push(profile);


//Create a new profile
var profile2 = { 
  id: 10000,
  name: " ",

};

profile2.id=5;
ppl_arr.push(profile2);
```